# Google Bot Robots.txt tester not working

Tags: wordpress, robots.txt, googlebot

txt tester not working in my case. I have the below lines in robots.txt.

But in the Tester  if i test wp-admin the tools showing allowed. I dont know why? please help me how to disallow wp-admin

```
 User-Agent: Googlebot
Allow: *.css*
Allow: *.js*
Allow: /*.jpg
Allow: /*.gif
Allow: /*.png

User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin
Disallow: /wp-admin
Disallow: /wp-includes
Disallow: /wp-content/plugins
Disallow: /wp-content/cache
Disallow: /wp-content/themes
Disallow: /category
Disallow: /tag
Disallow: /page
Disallow: /author
Disallow: /trackback
Disallow: /*trackback
Disallow: /*trackback*
Disallow: /*/trackback
Disallow: /*?*
Disallow: /*.html/$
Disallow: /*feed*

# Google Image
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow:
Allow: /*

# Google AdSense
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google*
Disallow:
Allow: /*
```

Comment: Which path did you test exactly? `wp-admin`, `/wp-admin`, `/wp-admin/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the trailing slash, you'll pass, or if you put a page after the wp-admin in the tester, you'd also see your rule would pass (block the bots) like /wp-admin/admin.php

```
User-agent:  *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /wp-admin
Disallow: /recommended/
Disallow: /comments/feed/
Disallow: /trackback/
Disallow: /index.php
Disallow: /xmlrpc.php
```

Comment: am getting allowed in tester. So its mean searchable by bots right?

Comment: i want to disallow the wp-admin and so on mentioned in the questions.

Comment: So you updated your rule to what I posted?  Then what.

Comment: What link is allowed? wp-admin or wp-admin/something.php ?

Comment: All 3 allowing that why am worried

Comment: Unless you have either another robots.txt in place or some more lines in your current robots.txt, then it should work as described.  Here is a screen shot https://snag.gy/RKsaMj.jpg

Comment: Thanks Howard. I have added my added my entire robots.txt code

Comment: For this aslo am getting the same. I dont know what is the issue